# Должна ли литература чему-то учить?

Tags: литература

Я сейчас выскажу свою точку зрения на литературу. Мне всегда казалось, что на писателе лежит огромная ответственность: книга - это своего рода трибуна, с которой он вещает для огромной аудитории читателей. И, соответственно, писатель должен сознавать эту ответственность и понимать, что его книга будет чему-то учить читателя. Но некоторые авторы, по-моему, рассматривают литературу ради литературы: поиграть словами, излить какие-то свои комплексы, что-то еще. К подобной литературе я, например, отношу набоковскую "Лолиту" (признаться, никогда не мог понять, чем ценна книжка про старого козла, который спит с 14-летней девчонкой).

А вы как считаете: какие задачи у литературы?

Answer (score 5):

Литература никому ничего не должна. Тем более учить. Это не учебник, а тонкая настройка органов чувств. Как хорошая музыка развивает музыкальный слух, так хорошая литература развивает способность чувствовать и воображать, расширяет границы сознания. Критерий искусства - особая, эстетическая эмоция (не путать с эйфорией), которую оно вызывает. А культура восприятия искусства в том, чтобы не перепутать эту эмоцию с жизнью.

Что касается задач, каждый писатель формулирует их для себя сам - на то оно и творчество, чтобы быть свободным.

Для меня суть художественного творчества формулируется так (не помню, кто это сказал): "есть такие проблемы, решение которых - в привычке к ним". Вечные, в принципе нерешаемые проблемы нуждаются хотя бы в осознании и принятии, в чем и помогает литература.

Кстати, вот как сам Набоков отвечает на вопрос, почему он написал "Лолиту":

"Это было интересно. В конце концов, почему вообще я написал свои книги? Во имя удовольствия, во имя сложности. Я не пишу с социальным умыслом и не преподаю нравственного урока, не эксплуатирую общие идеи — просто я люблю сочинять загадки с изящными решениями".

Comment: Тогда как не спросить: в чем загадка "Лолиты" и какие решения уже предложены?

Comment: Набоков об этом не сказал:) Возможно,загадка - само чувство любви, которое возникает там, где его быть не должно, а изящное решение в том, что девочка выросла. Это действительно изящно: педофилия, позор, осуждение, муки принятия решения, бегство... Кажется, выхода нет. А девочка раз - и выросла. И чувство прошло.

Comment: ... и сказала Гумберту: "Он всего лишь разбил мне сердце, а ты..." (не досказанным осталось "разбил мне жизнь").


Даже в высшей степени изящно описанная мерзость мерзостью быть не перестаёт. По-настоящему любящий не может годами причинять страшный вред тому, кого любит.

Answer (score 3):

Литература ни чему не учит. Вы ни чему не учите, когда рассказываете домочадцам, что купили в магазине. Автор по сути делает тоже самое рассказывает в той или иной степени выдуманную историю. Просто автор произведения, так же как и вы общаясь с человеком, вольно или невольно передаёт свой опыт, своё видение мира. Чем наблюдательнее и умнее писатель или рассказчик, тем больше полезных сведений мы способны почерпнуть. Чтение книг нас наделяет опытом общения с людьми, с которыми нам возможно никогда не довелось бы пообщаться в жизни. Узнать их чувства переживания, мотивы действий. Чтобы пообщаться с тем же количеством типажей, что представлены в "Войне и мире" Толстого, нам бы пришлось потратить десятилетия на общение с разными людьми. Причём это касается не только литературы реализма, так как даже в целиком фантастических произведениях мы наблюдаем людские характеры, придуманные человеком. Кстати, возможно именно из-за того, что благодаря интернету у людей появилась возможность получать информацию о людских типажах в быстром темпе напрямую от этих людей, чтение книг стало менее популярным явлением.

Что касается "Лолиты" Набокова. Есть ряд произведений искусства, которые не обязательно видеть, главное знать, что они существуют. К таким произведениям относятся те творения. где автор расширяет грани дозволенного в литературе, описывает то чего ещё на страницах книг ещё не встречалось. К таким произведениям можно отнести и "Лолиту" Набокова. Ни в пуританской Америке, ни в России так откровенно и образно преступное вожделение не описывали. Читать роман или нет, это уже дело вкуса, но знать о нём нужно.

Comment: @илья, у меня не было прошлого варианта ответа. Случайно нажал галку, сделав вопрос общим, потом изменил, вот и всё редактирование.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала давайте определимся с понятиями.

1) Что Вы считаете литературой?

2) Кого Вы называете писателями?

3) По какой методике Вы предлагаете определять, учит книга читателя или не учит? Кто в контрольной группе?

Answer (score 2):

Я очень люблю сравнивать литературу с живописью.Вот, к примеру, мы стоим перед признанным мировым шедевром. Какие чувства вызывает в вас картина, какие задевает душевные струны? Или может быть, вас поражает умение  так правдиво изображать мир в красках? А кто-то рядом с вами  увлеченно обсуждает технику живописи, у профессиональных художников свои, особые критерии мастерства. Но, кажется, никто не задает вопроса о смысле картины, о том, чему она нас учит. И тем не менее, искусство учит. Учит зоркости и внимательному отношению к окружающему миру.

В литературе все точно также. Вот писатель нашел тему, которая его волнует. Он хочет поделиться ею с нами, читателями. Но при этом лучшее, что он может сделать, - это создать правдивую картину жизни. Художественная литература не учит напрямую, она вводит нас в особое пространство, в котором мы сами для себя должны сделать все выводы. Автор может обозначить свою позицию и часто делает это, но читатель вовсе не обязан разделять его точку зрения.

А у Набокова мне очень нравится автобиографическая книга "Другие берега". Там и удивительная точность и выразительность языка, и мастерски изображенное течение жизни. Читатель без труда может представить себя на месте героя и решить по-своему стоящие перед ним нравственные проблемы.  И думаю, это будет лучшим уроком, который можно извлечь из литературы.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Интересная эта мысль – «я не эксплуатирую общие идеи».  Наверное,  набоковскую  «Лолиту» (или подобные книги) нужно прочитать каждому, только тогда человек  сможет лучше понять себя.   Он как бы заглянет в некое правдивое зеркало.  Есть книги и есть герои, которые всем видятся  примерно одинаково, поэтому в таком восприятии трудно выявить что-то глубоко личностное. Но какие разнообразные чувства вызывает в нас «Лолита»! Мы гневно осуждаем или пытаемся понять, отвергаем или ищем оправдание? Некоторые философы считают, что  человек особенно нетерпимо относится к таким качествам, которые  глубоко скрыты в нем самом.  Поэтому по возможности  стоит прочитаь или перечитать «Лолиту».

Comment: Не знаю... У меня, кроме омерзения, "Лолита" никаких чувств не вызвала

Comment: "Некоторые философы считают, что человек особенно нетерпимо относится к таким качествам, которые глубоко скрыты в нем самом."

Подавляющее большинство людей не приемлют людоедства. Следовательно, все мы в глубине души людоеды?

Если мне встретится кто-то вроде героя Набокова - убью голыми руками. С особой жестокостью. При этом женщины в силу ряда психологических отличий не могут испытывать потребности в педофилии. Если такие случаи и имеют место, объясняются они банальной распущенностью. Так что никаких "таких качеств" в глубине многих гумбертоненавистников не скрыто.

Answer (score 0):

1) Литература настоящая - это иллюзорный мир выдуманных сюжетов, персонажей и ситуаций, дающий возможность автору проявить себя, как портному, а читателю - примерить сшитую им  одежду на себя. Как всякая одежда, литература подразделяется на модную, стильную, высококачественную, сделанную из ценного материала, ширпотреб и проч. Самая ценная литература - одиночное изделие, которое можно носить по великим праздникам, которым можно гордиться (даже если его нет в личной собственности), которым можно любоваться, снимая с вешалки и вспоминая дорогие, памятные ситуации, связанные с личной жизнью. Литература насторящая не любит общественного обсуждения, потому что она - очень личная литература, она скорее чувственная, нежели языковая. Закончу каламбуром: литература настоящая - это настоящая литература. Сюда же следует отнести поэзию, драматургию. Окололитература: мемуары, воспоминания, некоторые критические работы (вроде работ В. Г. Белинского), в том числе касающиеся музыки, живописи и проч. 2) Писатели - портные настоящей литературы. 3) Пока не знаю. Может статься, таковой нет, потому что и писатели разные, и читатели - тоже...    Это скорее ответ [@yupaz](/users/1370/yupaz), нежели ответ по-существу... А по существу вопроса: "Лолиту" не читал, так же, как "Декамерон" и многое подобное, зная о направлении сюжетов. Мне кажется, это чтение напоминает подглядывание через замочную скважину с прибором ночного видения в спальню молодожёнов в первую их брачную ночь

Answer (score 0):

Модальность неправильная. Как там было?.. "история учит нас тому, что история нас ничему не учит"? Не знаю, как с историей, а литература так очень даже учит. **Фактически** учит (неважно, *должна* или нет). Например, русская литература XIX века научила (подучила, побудила) большевиков сделать революцию (Карл Маркс дал только теорию).

Случай с Набоковым тоже нас кое-чему учит: любая бездарность может создать бестселлер, грамотно используя грязные технологии.

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с тем, что художественная литература никому ничего не должна(исключим детскую, конечно).

Насчет  "Лолиты" не могу не высказаться. [Источник](http://licey.net/free/15-analiz_proizvedenii_zarubezhnyh_pisatelei_biografii_inostrannyh_pisatelei/62-amerikanskaya_literatura/stages/2169-v_nabokov_roman_lolita.html). Впервые об этом услышала в лекции по зарубежной литературе.

Между тем "Лолита" — менее всего роман о прискорбном и частном клиническом случае с криминальной окраской. Это лишь самый поверхностный пласт произведения. И даже не только история болезненной, греховной, извращенной, а потому обреченной, но настоящей любви. Прежде всего, это и роман об искусстве и художнике. Судьба Гумберта Гумберта, его одержимость и мания, блаженство и проклятие, судорожное стремление приручить и удержать "бессмертного демона во образе маленькой девочки" — есть метафора творческого процесса. В середине XX века о подобных вещах можно говорить уже только с горькой самоиронией, если не c самоиздевкой, которая адаптируется в общепонятные на Западе термины фрейдовского психоанализа, в "либидобелиберду", как припечатывает его Набоков.
Это и зашифрованная автобиография самого художника, что, разумеется, не следует понимать буквально: Гумберт — Набоков примерно в том же смысле, какой Флобер вкладывал в слова: "Эмма Бовари — это я". И, наконец, обобщающий план: данный роман — это аллегория взаимоотношений художника Набокова с Америкой, пусть тронутой современной массовой культурой, но все еще "огромной, прекрасной, доверчивой страной", чей нынешний облик и литературное достояние прошлого он изощренным образом использовал для собственного одностороннего интеллектуального наслаждения.
Любовь и вожделение утонченного европейца Гумберта Гумберта к американской девочке-подростку Долорес Гейз — это метафорическое изображение "романа автора с английским языком" и его метаморфозы в американского писателя. И в данном плане Лолита, чьей душой герой тщится завладеть, колеся сначала с ней, а потом в погоне за ней по американским городам и весям, выступает воплощением самой современной Америки.
"Лолита" — действительно книга об Америке, самый американский из всех американских романов Набокова. Это и своего рода дорожный атлас и каталог реалий жизни США середины века — современного "культурного мусора", и вместе с тем своеобразная антология американской литературы XIX—XX столетий. Роман изобилует разнообразнейшими отсылками к литературе США. Он пестрит фамилиями известных американских писателей. Так постоянно упоминается ключевое здесь имя Э. По и вскользь — Т.С. Элиота. В книге фигурируют некто доктор Купер, ухаживавший за тетушкой героя, а Оливер Холмс, один из "бостонских браминов", предстает в шутовском облике первого любовника Лолиты Чарли Холмса, мальчишки, "к умственным способностям которого даже она относилась с нескрываемым презрением". При желании этот перечень может быть продолжен.